# where are old function of qgssymbol

Tags: qgis, c++, feature-class

in the new version of qgis 2.8, in the c++ API and in the class QgsSymbolV2, a lot of function has been deleted, by exemple setfillcolor, setcustomtexture, setnamedpoint, setpointsize

i would like to know if these function are useless in the 2.8 version ? or they had been moved to another classes ?

please help